# Multi-index pivoting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Consider the following dataframe:

```
         item_id  hour    when        date      quantity
110   0YrKNYeEoa     1  before  2015-01-26        247286
111   0UMNiXI7op     1  before  2015-01-26        602001
112   0QBtIMN3AH     1  before  2015-01-26        981630
113   0GuKXLiWyV     1  after   2015-01-26       2203913
114   0SoFbjvXTs     1  after   2015-01-26        660183
115   0UkT257SXj     1  before  2015-01-26        689332
116   0RPjXnkiGx     1  after   2015-01-26        283090
117   0FhJ9RGsLT     1  before  2015-01-26       2024256
118   0FhGJ4MFlg     1  before  2015-01-26         74524
119   0FQhHZRXhB     1  before  2015-01-26             0
120   0FsSdJQlTB     1  before  2015-01-26             0
121   0FrrAzTFHE     1  before  2015-01-26             0
122   0FfkgBdMHi     1  before  2015-01-26             0
123   0FOnJNexRn     1  before  2015-01-26             0
124   0FcWhIdBds     1  before  2015-01-26             0
125   0F2lr0cL9t     1  before  2015-01-26       1787659
```

I would like to pivot it to get the table arranged as:

```
Index                     before           after
(item_id, hour, date)   quantityB      quantityA
```

When I try with:

```
df.pivot(index=['item_id', 'hour', 'date'], columns='when', values='quanty')
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8143, placement implies 3
```

Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking I think what you want is `pandas.pivot_table(...)` which you can use like so:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['item_id', 'hour', 'date'], columns='when', values='quantity')
```

which with a sample data frame of

```
    item_id  hour  when      date     quantity
0       a     1  before  2015-01-26        25
1       b     1  before  2015-01-26        14
2       a     1   after  2015-01-26         4
3       d     1  before  2015-01-26        43
4       b     1   after  2015-01-26        30
5       d     1   after  2015-01-26        12
```

produces

```
when                     after  before
item_id hour date                     
a       1    2015-01-26      4      25
b       1    2015-01-26     30      14
d       1    2015-01-26     12      43
```

Comment: Wow. OK, I just realized that `pivot` and `pivot_table` are two different methods.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina Did this solution answer your question?

Comment: Yes -- Thanks, I was reading about both methods and testing it locally.