# Getting No numeric types to aggregate error when using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

I know this should be really easy but I keep getting errors when trying to pivot.  I'm getting my data from psycopg2

```
cur.execute("select * from table")
arr=cur.fetchall()
pdres=pandas.DataFrame(arr, columns=['pricedate',hour', 'node','dart'])
pdres=pdres.set_index(['pricedate','hour','node'])
```

Here is where stuff stops working...

```
pdres.pivot(index=['pricedate','hour'],columns='node',values='dart')
```

results in Wrong number of items passed 720, placement implies 2

That brought me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225465/multi-index-pivoting-in-pandas) which led me to doing this

```
pandas.pivot_table(pdres, index=['pricedate','hour'], columns='node', values='dart')
```

This tells me 'No numeric types to aggregate

That led me to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html but I'm not sure the right syntax of it (when to use it), and I also don't even know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: You don't need the line `pdres=pdres.set_index(['pricedate','hour','node'])`, as `pivot` works on the columns.

Comment: And BTW, you can also use `pd.read_sql_query("select * from table", con)` for the first three lines

Comment: @joris thanks to your suggestion and even more googling I found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes to make it work:

- First don't `set_index`
- Second, don't use `convert_objects`. Do use `astype`

Specifically, the following works:

```
cur.execute("select * from table")
arr = cur.fetchall()
pdres = pandas.DataFrame(arr, columns=['pricedate', 'hour', 'node', 'dart'])
pdres['dart'] = pdres['dart'].astype(float)
pdres = pandas.pivot_table(pdres, index=['pricedate','hour'], columns='node', values='dart')
```